# Should a HttpResponse's status_code attribute be an integer or a string?

Tags: python, django, types

When I am creating a HttpResponse object, should I pass it a integer for the `status_code` attribute, or a string? I.e. `HttpResponse('401 Client Error', status=401)` vs. `HttpResponse('401 Client Error', status="401")`

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code) is a generic descriptor, that doesn't give the type.

> **HttpResponse.status_code**
>
> The HTTP status code for the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always pass an **integer**.

```
HttpResponse('401 Client Error', status=401)
```

As per the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html):

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
>   attempt to understand and satisfy the request.

Answer (score 3):

**An integer**, because the default value listed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__) is an integer. I.e. 200, instead of "200".

Building from [Rahul Gupta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786868/should-a-httpresponses-status-code-attribute-be-an-integer-or-a-string/30787713#30787713), an integer also because quote HTTP protocol,

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request.

and because headers and metadata may be either strings or integers